# Every finite abelian group admits a cyclic tower ending with trivial subgroup having all factor groups of prime order

Tags: abstract-algebra

I understand the first half of the question that for finite abelian group, we have a cyclic tower ending with the trivial subgroup.
I can’t see how we show that the factor groups will have prime order.
Any hints ?

Comment: Yes..so from a cyclic tower that ends with trivial subgroup , how we construct the required cyclic tower?

Comment: By refining it, until we reach what we want. Have a look here at the posts (e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428297/proving-that-every-finite-group-has-a-composition-series)). And note that a simple abelian group has prime order.